# How to run useEffect() when children change size in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I want to update the layout of a component when its children change size. I have a parent component `DetailView` that composes dynamic child components, which may change size as the user manipulates them. When this happens, I want the parent component to refresh the layout.

EDIT: I am concerned with the size of the children rendered on screen, not the number of children.

Each time a component in the layout changes size I need to run the `updateLayout()` function. I do now want to pass the `updateLayout()` function to each child as a prop, which I view as undesirable coupling between the child components and the layout system.

The snippet below should illustrate what I want, but it doesn't fire when the children change size.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Children changed");
    updateLayout();
  }, Children.toArray(children));
```

Answer (score 1):

`children` is an array so all you have to do is add the `children.length` as a dependency array to `useEffect`

As soon as the chidren length changes then `updateLayout` function will get called.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Children changed");
    updateLayout();
}, [children.length]);
```

Comment: I think this would run useEffect when the number of children changes, but I want to update the layout when the size of an individual child changes.

Comment: `size of the individual child` means?

Comment: Meaning the amount of space the rendered child takes on the screen.

Comment: I don't find that parent components have access to children changes.
This is by design.  Could set up infinite loops.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` allows you to perform side effects from a function component. When `useEffect` is called, React knows to render your side effect **only after changes are made to the DOM**.  And changing children's size is just changing the style (CSS) And CSS **does not change the DOM** .